# Condensed Return Statement in Python

Tags: python, regex, list-comprehension

I'm working on an assignment for class where I'm using regular expressions to return the locations of all pattern matches in the specified string. If there are matches, I am to return the indices, and if no matches are found, I need to return None. I have done this successfully but would like to put the entire expression into a single line, as I have attempted to do in the commented return statements.

```
def searchMotif(sequence, motif):
    if not type(motif) is str:
        raise Exception("Invalid Motif")
    #matches = re.finditer(motif, sequence)
    #indices = [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in matches]

    indices = [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in re.finditer(motif, sequence)]
    if indices:
       return indices
    else:
       return None

    #return [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in matches]
    #return [(match.start(), match.end()) for match in re.finditer(motif, sequence)]
```

Ideally, I would like to have a statement that reads similar to
`return [(match.start(), match.end() for match in re.finditer(motif, sequence)] else None`. I know this syntax is incorrect, but I hope it gets across what I am trying to achieve. I am new to both regular expressions and list comprehension, so I'm not certain if you can use an if statement within my list comprehension.

Is it possible to populate a list via a Regex iterator and check if it's empty in a return statement?

Comment: In my opinion, you are doing too much in that line of code. For simpler tests, you can use a ternary operator (well, it's not an operator per se) in Python: return a if condition else b.

Comment: Instead of just downvoting something into oblivion you could explain why it's a bad question to help improve future ones.....

Comment: @jarmod yeah I realize that; I'll look into breaking it up more. Just trying to figure out how to write these expressions at this point!

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't down-vote your question.

Comment: @jarmod wasn't especially directed at you in particular, you just happened to comment before I did haha :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
def test(): 
    return [] or None   

print(test())
```

Output:

```
None
```

The reason is, that any empty iterable (set,dict,list,string,...) is considered `False`

for your code that would be:

```
return indices or None # no if indices: needed
```

Readup here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing

> [...] most of the built-in objects considered false:
>
> - constants defined to be false: None and False.
> - zero of any numeric type: 0, 0.0, 0j, Decimal(0), Fraction(0, 1)
> - empty sequences and collections: '', (), [], {}, set(), range(0)
>
> [...]

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept when the time limit runs out.